# Building java gradle project with vsts ,building even with errors and show build succeeded

Tags: java, gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have followed the guidelines mentioned in the VSTS documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/java/build-gradle?view=vsts&tabs=vsts, and created a build definition for my java project.

As per documentation, my code has any errors in build summary it should display that build failed.

But, even though my project does not build successfully in local, in VSTS it's showing build successfully.

Can anyone suggest me, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you build the project? are you sure you have built the project and got the correct artifacts? If it is, then you just need to debug your local environment.

Comment: thank you for your replay Andy Li-MSFT now it is working fine i hosted in own server and before that the issue is project is not build